# Getting Friends List Empty Facebook SDK 3.8 in Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to fetch friends' list in `Facebook SDK 3.8` but it returning `Empty User List`.
I have also set the permissions of `user_friends`. Please see the following code.

```
<code>
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends"));

    Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
                        Log.i("activitytag", "UserListSize: " + users.size());

                    }
                });
                request.executeAsync();
</code>
```

I am getting the `UserListSize` to `0`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you created your app after April 30, 2014, then you're using version 2.0 of the graph API, in which case the newMyFriendsRequest will only return friends who are also using your app. You should also update your SDK to the latest (3.14.1).

Comment: I am using `Facebook SDK 3.14.1` but still having the same issue. How can i achieve this? Can you please help me out

Comment: Using 3.14.1 doesn't change the fact that you can only get friends who also use your app. That's an API change with 2.0.

Comment: What should i used to fetch the friends list?

Comment: The quick answer is, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

In facebook api v2.0 has no way to get all friends list.
but if you want to get all friend list ONLY IN GAME then you can call 
Either

Invitable Friends List:
you may use the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends API.
OR
Taggable Friends List:

the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends

for more detail please read facebook change log:

[Facebook Change log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)